Problems with Bracket Pair Colorization in vs code
Why Bracket Pair Colorization not working when i use double bracket?
Not working
But, if I add a space between the two brackets this working:
Working

The problem is that when I save the file this space between brackets is deleted and it looks as in the first image.

My configuration to bracket pair is:
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.independentColorPoolPerBracketType": true,
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
  "editor.guides.bracketPairsHorizontal": "active",
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs": "active",
  "editor.matchBrackets": "always",

What i tried
I already tried modifying editorBracketHighlight.foreground from 1 to 6 inside workbench.colorCustomizations, but it doesn't work.
I tried other options within workbench.colorCustomization but they didn't work either.

@serm5902 use this extension in VSCode: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=leodevbro.blockman. I have been using it for years and best solution for bracketing issues

what language mode is this editor in? check the language mode indicator in the statusbar

the lenguage mode is JavaScript React, although I also tried Babel Javascript. But none of them work.
